# Android local service registration

Tags: android, android-service

This is driving me crazy. I have created a local service which monitors the accelerometer. Sometimes the service works and sometimes it does not. It seems that the service keeps just randomly unregistering itself.

The service reacts after a certain level of movement on the phone. The thing is that if I start the service, I can end it correctly right after. However, after I shake the phone (set off how the service should act) nothing happens and then when I try to turn off the service I get an error. What is really confusing me is that I have put break codes in my code which detects the movement, and the code which is called after a movement isn't even being executed.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Here is my code for the service and its manager.

```
public class AccelService extends Service {
    public static boolean listening = false;
    private static Context CONTEXT;
    private static Sensor sensor;
    private static SensorManager ASensorManager;

    private static SensorEventListener accelEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        private float x = 0;
        private float y = 0;
        private float z = 0;
        private double max = 0;
        private double force = 0;

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            z = event.values[2];
            force = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
            if (force > max)
                max = force;

            if (force > AccelManager.dropValue)                
                AccelManager.onDrop(force);                
        } 
    };

private static void startListener() {
    ASensorManager = (SensorManager) CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = ASensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (sensors.size() > 0) {
        sensor = sensors.get(0);
        listening = ASensorManager.registerListener(accelEventListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        AccelManager.setListening(listening);
    }
} 

private final IBinder mBinder = new AccelBinder();

public class AccelBinder extends Binder {
    AccelService getService() {
        return AccelService.this;
    }
}

public void onCreate() {
    CONTEXT = this;
    startListener();
}

public boolean isListening() {
    return listening;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
}

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        return AccelService.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (listening)
        stopListening();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public static void stopListening() {  
        AccelManager.setListening(false);
        try {
            if (ASensorManager != null && accelEventListener != null)
                ASensorManager.unregisterListener(accelEventListener);            
        } catch (Exception e) {}     
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
```

Here is the Manager class.

```
public class AccelManager extends Activity {

    public static Boolean isListening = false;
    private static Boolean callMade = false;
    public static Context ctxt;
    public static int dropValue = 100;
    private static Intent i;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        ctxt = context;
        i = getIntent();
    }


    public void activateService(Boolean check) {
        if (check)
            doBindService();
        else {
            if (isListening) {
                if (AccelWatch != null) {
                    AccelWatch.stopSelf();
                    doUnbindService();
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    public static void onDrop(double force){
        if (!callMade) {
            Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Phone dropped: " + force, 5000).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(ctxt,DropDetected.class);
            AccelWatch.stopSelf();
            doUnbindService();
            callMade = true;
            ctxt.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    private void doBindService() {
        if (!isListening) {
            i = new Intent(ctxt,AccelService.class);
            ctxt.bindService(i, AccelConnection, ctxt.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

    private static void doUnbindService() {
        if (isListening)         
            ctxt.unbindService(AccelConnection);
    }    

    public void setDropValue(int drop) {
        dropValue = drop;
    }

    public boolean isRunning(){
        return AccelWatch.isListening();
    }

    public static void setListening(Boolean listen){
        isListening = listen;
    }

    private static AccelService AccelWatch;

    private static ServiceConnection AccelConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)     {
            AccelWatch = ((AccelService.AccelBinder)service).getService();
            AccelWatch.startService(i);

            Toast.makeText(ctxt, "The service is binded.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            AccelWatch = null;
            Toast.makeText(ctxt, "The service was disconnected.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if you are thinking about attempting to make a Service that runs forever you should think about not doing so. Services that run all the time are really bad for battery life.

That aside, I would suggest getting rid of

```
    AccelWatch.startService(i);
```

in `onServiceConnected()`.

When you bind to a service, the service is started automatically, and `onServiceConnected()` is the asynchronous callback you get. So, you may effectively be attempting to restart your Service with that line.

Don't ever do this

```
    private static Context CONTEXT;
```

and then,

```
    CONTEXT = this;
```

You have just guaranteed that you will leak your Service (and your Activity as you did it there as well) as static references exist for the life of the application - not the life of the Service. Just use "this" if you need a context. You are already inside your Service/Activity.

Another source of leaking your service is here....

```
public class AccelBinder extends Binder {
     AccelService getService() {
         return AccelService.this;
     }
 }
```

This inner class is not static. In java this means that the inner class has a reference to the outer class. There is a bug (Issue 6426) in Android that means the system will always leak your binder. If your binder has a reference to the Service (as non-static inner classes do) then you will leak the service as well.

`ServiceonStart()` is deprecated  since Version 5 (Android 1.6) as there are less than 7% of devices using this version I would suggest dropping it at least until you get your Service working - so that you don't have to think about it.

See how you get on with that. Persist with Services they are quite easy - it just takes a little bit of adjustment the first time (lifecycles etc)

As these problems are common - I decided to write a blog here to provide a little guidance

http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android

The example uses the binding method of using a Service rather than `onStart()` - but I have tried to place things in context a little for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logs to see what happened causing the service unregistering, and you can check whether there is exception of the service in the logcat view.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on how I would do that? I'm not very experienced with logcat.

Comment: Upon further looking, it seems that I keep leaking the ServiceConnection somewhere...